# How to wire a 6-pin relay?

Tags: switches, relay, wiring, load

I have the relay described in this [datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/5e52/0900766b81663fe0.pdf). I have the z-type. It has 6 pins on the bottom.

I want to control this relay with an Arduino device and all it has to do is work like a switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fouHS3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How do I wire up my relay to function like this? Do I need to use all 6 pins? I don't understand the wiring diagram in the datasheet at all: -

[image]

I want to know what each pin on the relay does. Between which pins should I connect my load? Which pin controls the state of the relay?

Comment: There is really not enough info. Are you askng what the pins on the relay are, or what circuit is needed to contol it with an MCU? Which also depends on which relay model it is to know the coil voltage, and what voltages you have available to drive the coil?

Comment: @Justme Yes, I want to know what each pin on the relay does. Between which pins should I connect my load? Which pin controls the state of the relay?

Comment: @Carl It would appear to be another Chinese quality datasheet. The two pins separate to the right are the coil, nothing else makes sense.

Comment: @Lundin And in all other data sheets the white rectangle is the coil so what you suggest makes no sense. There are also other relays with 1Z contact arrangement and they match this relay.

Comment: @Justme How are you going to design the relay electrically as well as mechanically with the coil on those middle pins? That doesn't make any sense. Here's another "1 form C 1Z" https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/622790/DBLectro/HG4124L/1.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't trust this datasheet. Hongfa is a big, well-known manufacturer and I use their products myself, but documentation isn't their strongest suite. So I wouldn't trust this datasheet but connect one of these to a lab supply and beep up the relay tongues before anything else. Or you could pry one open and look at the tongues - on literally every PCB relay I've ever used (and pried open), the tongues are always on one side and the coil on the other. Also if someone thinks 2,54mm is sufficient clearance/creepage for 125VAC 4A please make an argument about that.

Comment: @Lundin I don't know how one would design a relay like that - that's mechanical engineering. A relay with type QY23-012DC-Z has same pinout and data sheets show the coil as a coil. And the OP's relay is a signal relay, not intended for 4A 125VAC which can be just found by looking at the data sheet.

Comment: @Justme I got those numbers from said datasheet, though at closer inspection it seems it's just rated for 62.6VAC/2A. Still it's all very strange and it's good engineering to question the spec, especially based on experience of how every other relay out there is designed. I might be wrong, but the only way to find out is experimenting with a physical relay.

Comment: And btw the part which _is_ intended for 4A 125VAC got the same layout and 2,54mm pitch. So either they designed the strangest, most useless relay I've ever seen or the datasheet is wrong...

Comment: @Carl - Hi, Re: "*I have the relay*" Great! A physical test will help. As you see, there are concerns that the relay pinout in that datasheet doesn't match the common standard pinout. Can you please measure the resistance across the pins described in [this answer](/a/660455), especially the two pins across the white rectangle in the datasheet? The nominal coil resistances for the different voltage & standard/sensitive relay versions are listed in the datasheet e.g. 5 V relay coil is either 125 Ω or 167 Ω. Do you measure the expected coil resistance across  those "white rectangle" pins? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson Sorry for the *very* late reply. Measuring the resistance across the middle pins gives a resistance of \$150 \: \Omega\$. I guess that means that the two middle pins truly are the terminals of the coil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white rectangle is the coil so you drive the two pins leading to the coil.

The two pins on right are both the switch contact common terminal.

The pin on bottom left is the normally open switch contact.

Comment: What? The white rectangle on the schematic is _NOT_ the coil. These are standardized pin-outs, it's always the two separate pins that go to the coil. The datasheet is admittedly quite confusing.

Comment: @Lundin But the white rectangle is the coil in the relay wiring diagram given. Two pins leading to the white rectangle are the coil pins. If they aren't then give a correct answer.